# Detection of Eclipse being in a headless mode

Tags: eclipse, headless

I have one plugin which is expecting to have a Display present all the time and I would like to modify it in such way that it will not try to display things when the eclipse is run with the -nosplash mode as headless.

I wonder how to detect this mode properly from within the plugin, would something like this work?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html#getInputArguments()

Comment: "-nosplash" and headless are not the same thing. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835474/add-headless-capability-to-existing-eclipse-plugin.  And this: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/104201/

Comment: Yes, you are right, I think you answered it. I will check it tomorrow, but would you consider it posting it as answer in case it will work out?